# Special characters in Nokogiri Builder

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a street name input  like "August Allebéplein", and am creating  XML  using Nokogiri:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
 xml.Street 'August Allebéplein'
end
```

The result is:

```
<Street>August Alleb&#xE9;plein</Street>
```

How can make Nokogiri include special characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(encoding: 'UTF-8') do |xml|
  xml.Street 'August Allebéplein'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :)